# Adding metadata fields to Default Multimedia Schema

Tags: 2013-sp1

We have approx. around 12 sites in Live which are using Default Multimedia Schema for image binaries. There is a need to add some additional information to these image binaries, hence I am planning to add metadata fields by editing Default Multimedia Schema. Do you see any challenges in the long run due to editing Tridion's Default Multimedia schema?

Appreciate your suggestions/help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not challenges as such, but be aware that any fields you add will not be added to existing multimedia components until they have been edited. Also, if you have the schema set as the default for a publication and you add mandatory fields with no default value, then you will not be able to upload multimedia components via WebDAV unless you change the linked schema for the folder you are uploading to.

Remember that the Default Multimedia Schema will be BluePrinted right from the very top of your BluePrint chain (i.e. the Primary Parent). You may wish to consider creating a new copy of that schema in your schema publication, adding your metadata there, changing the default for your publications and updating your other schemas/code so that they can use both the old and new types.

Comment: Thank you David. One more concern is related to Hot fixes, patches from SDL Tridion. Does the installation of hot fixes, patches will override my changes(metadata) in Default Multimedia schema?

Comment: I'm not aware of any issues related to changes to the Default Multimedia Schema and patches or upgrade scripts in the past. If there were any in  future, I would consider them a bug. I'm sure that anything coming from SDL in future would not simply overwrite or reset your changes unless for good reason and with good documentation if that were the case.